# Pyomo CBC 1.#j error

Tags: pyomo, cbc

I am using to solve my model Pyomo/CBC combination. But rarely, CBC Gap shows 1.#j and pyomo generate an error. Hence, it doesn't get solution. How can I solve this problem?

Screen output:

```
Result - Stopped on time limit

Objective value:                26848000.00000000
Lower bound:                    0.000
Gap:                            1.#J
Enumerated nodes:               336653
Total iterations:               620783
Time (CPU seconds):             62.14
Time (Wallclock seconds):       62.14

Total time (CPU seconds):       62.15   (Wallclock seconds):       62.15

ERROR:writeSql:could not convert string to float: '1.#J'
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.
opt_success = opt.solve(model, tee=True)
File "C:\Users\python\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages
\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 605, in solve
result = self._postsolve()
File "C:\Users\python\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages
\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\CBCplugin.py", line 870, in _postsolve
results = super(CBCSHELL, self)._postsolve()
File "C:\Users\python\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages
\pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py", line 270, in _postsolve
results = self.process_output(self._rc)
File "C:\Users\python\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages
\pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py", line 327, in process_output
results = self.process_logfile()
File "C:\Users\python\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages
\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\CBCplugin.py", line 563, in process_logfile
gap = float(tokens[1])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.#J'
Error <class 'ValueError'> value could not convert string to float: '1.#J' diger
<traceback object at 0x000000000D0F0288>
```

My solution is changing CBCplugin.py related line with try-except. But I can not predict potential side effects on pyomo.

My answer:
I changed CBCplugin.py, line 563:

```
 gap = float(tokens[1])
```

with:

```
  try:
      gap = float(tokens[1])
  except:
      gap = 0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.#J` in C++ is the output obtained when printing a formatted double equal to infinity (`1.#INF`). See [this related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840081/what-does-floating-point-error-1-j-mean).

The CBC gap is computed this way in [`CbcSolver.cpp`](https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc/blob/master/src/CbcSolver.cpp):

```
if (babModel_->bestSolution()) {
  sprintf(generalPrint + strlen(generalPrint),
    "Gap:                            %.2f\n",
    (babModel_->getObjValue() - babModel_->getBestPossibleObjValue()) / fabs(babModel_->getBestPossibleObjValue()));
}
```

If `babModel_->getBestPossibleObjValue()` is equal to `0.0`, you will obtain a gap of `1.#INF` which will then be formatted to `1.#J`. This is also what other solvers do, see for example [Gurobi MIPGap documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/mipgap.html) which returns infinity in such case. Note that this matches your outputted lower bound of `0.000`.

As for pyomo, returning a gap of 0 could be wrong in most cases, that is, unless the best solution is also 0. Returning some form of infinity, such as `numpy.inf`, could be the correct solution. Although I didn't check if pyomo would handle that gracefully. Looking quickly trough the other pyomo solver plugins, I don't see any handling of a MIP gap being anything other than a float, which seems problematic.